# SQLSRV Equilavent of mysqli_stmt_bind_result

Tags: php, sql-server, database, azure, sqlsrv

I am working on a registration/login form and this is my first time working with SQLSRV(Because of a Azure Database) and i can't seem to find a equilavent of `mysqli_stmt_bind_result` for SQLSRV could somebody help me with this?
Thanks in Advance, Thomas

Answer (score 0):

I think that your function is `sqlsrv_fetch_array()`.

You can check this simple example:

```
<?php
$server = 'server\instance,port';
$cinfo = array(
    "Database"=>'master',
    "UID"=>'user',
    "PWD"=>'password'
);

$conn = sqlsrv_connect($server, $cinfo);
if( $conn === false )
{
    echo "Error (sqlsrv_connect): ".print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true);
    exit;
}

$sql = 
    "SELECT 'SUSER_SNAME' AS [NAME], CONVERT(varchar(128), SUSER_SNAME()) AS [VALUE]".
    "UNION ALL ".
    "SELECT 'SUSER_NAME' AS [NAME], CONVERT(varchar(128), SUSER_NAME()) AS [VALUE]".
    "UNION ALL ".
    "SELECT 'USER_NAME' AS [NAME], CONVERT(varchar(128), USER_NAME()) AS [VALUE]".
    "UNION ALL ".
    "SELECT 'USER_ID' AS [NAME], CONVERT(varchar(128), USER_ID()) AS [VALUE]";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);
if( $stmt === false ) {
    echo "Error (sqlsrv_query): ".print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true);
    exit;
}

while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo $row['NAME'].": ".$row['VALUE']."</br>";
}

sqlsrv_free_stmt($stmt);
sqlsrv_close($conn);
?>
```

Example using parameters:

```
...
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Gebruikers WHERE username = (?) AND password = (?)";
// $params definition:
// - A literal value.
// - A PHP variable.
// - An array with the following structure:
// array($value [, $direction [, $phpType [, $sqlType]]]) where $direction is one of the following: SQLSRV_PARAM_IN, SQLSRV_PARAM_OUT, SQLSRV_PARAM_INOUT. The default valueis SQLSRV_PARAM_IN.
$params = array(
    array($vusername, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
    array($vpassword, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN)
);
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql, $params);
if( $stmt === false ) {
    echo "Error (sqlsrv_query): ".print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true);
    exit;
}
while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $vusername = $row['username'];
    $vpassword = $row['password'];
}
'''
```

You can read more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/microsoft-php-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017).

Comment: I have `$sql = "SELECT * FROM Gebruikers WHERE username = '$vusername' AND password = '$vpassword'";` as query can I use my query to?

Comment: How can i output the data into variables? For example I want to output the data that comes back into `$vusername and $vpassword`

Comment: @Thomas Adema   If I understand correct the syntax of your query, you expect to be returned just one row as a resultset. I think that table 'Gebruikers' has at least columns 'username' and 'password'. So to get columns values, just do $vusername = $row['username'].
I've used extended $params syntax for updated example.

Comment: Okay I will try this. Thanks a lot in Advance!